# Array inside array from a database query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, codeigniter

I have a table of orders (`tbl_orders`).

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|invoice        | productid | qty | currentPrice |
+------------------------------------------------+
|139813018020   | 35        | 4   | 199          |
|139813018020   | 43        | 1   | 329          |
|139813307433   | 22        | 4   | 399          |
|139813307433   | 15        | 1   | 150          |
|139813307477   | 63        | 1   | 499          |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Each row will represent a single product.
A order may have one or more rows.

Eg. Invoice `139813018020` has 2 different products. `Product35` and `product43`, which are two rows. This is one whole order

I'm using a query like this:

```
SELECT invoice, productID, qty, currentPrice FROM tbl_orders
return $query->result_array() // codeigniter
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [invoice] => 139813018020
        [productID] => 35
        [qty] => 4
        [currentPrice] => 199
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [invoice] => 139813018020
        [productID] => 43
        [qty] => 1
        [currentPrice] => 329
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [invoice] => 139813307433
        [productID] => 22
        [qty] => 4
        [currentPrice] => 399
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [invoice] => 139813307433
        [productID] => 15
        [qty] => 1
        [currentPrice] => 150
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [invoice] => 139813307477
        [productID] => 63
        [qty] => 1
        [currentPrice] => 499
    )

)
```

I need **ONE** order and the products for that order

I need the array to look like something like this or similar:

```
Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        139813018020 => Array 
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                   [productID] => 35
                   [qty] => 4
                   [currentPrice] => 199
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                   [productID] => 43
                   [qty] => 1
                   [currentPrice] => 329
                )

         )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        139813018033 => Array 
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                   [productID] => 22
                   [qty] => 4
                   [currentPrice] => 399
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                   [productID] => 15
                   [qty] => 1
                   [currentPrice] => 150
                )

         )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        139813018077 => Array 
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                   [productID] => 63
                   [qty] => 1
                   [currentPrice] => 499
                )
         )
    )
)
```

I'm using php, mysqli and codeigniter.

Comment: I would select distinct invoice numbers, then cycle through the resulting array and query the product ID, QTY and PRICE for the one invoice number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to loop through your database array and build a new array with keys set to the `invoice` numbers. That way, each invoice number key references an array of the products ordered in that invoice.

Note that the method below has one fewer levels of depth as compared with your desired output. The keys of the root array are the invoice numbers, rather than being 0-indexed.

```
// get the array from your database
$arr=$query->result_array();

// initialize a new array
$newarr=array();

// loop through database array and add entries to new array
foreach ($arr as $entry) {
  $newarr[$entry['invoice']][] = array(
    'productID'    => $entry['productID'],
    'qty'          => $entry['qty'],
    'currentPrice' => $entry['currentPrice']
  );
}

// output new array
echo"<pre>".print_r($newarr,true)."</pre>";
```